# CSS image in navigation bar pushes text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an image with CSS on a navigation bar. Even if I resize the image it still pushes text down.

My div html code is:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src='images/tphome.png' border='0' width='24' height='24'> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nuSLH/

Is there away around this?

Comment: Your image lacks the mandatory `alt` attribute. Please see one of the "[WCAG 2.0 Technique](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html)" and this very good read at WebAIM: [Creating Accessible Images - Creating Effective Alternative (alt)Text](http://webaim.org/techniques/images/alt_text)

Comment: If you do use an `alt` attribute, in this case I would leave it empty. Since the most logical alternative text would be "Home" a screen reader would read "Home Home" when browsing the menu and that must be quite annoying. Edit: I wouldn't use an `img` here to begin with though. Presentational graphics belong in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a css class and :before instead of putting in an image since it is presentation and not really important to the content.

Changed this to add position: relative...

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

And then something like this... might have to add some padding to the li.

```
.icon-home:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    content: "";
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/1CRy2G5.png);
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

To add the class...

```
    <li><a class="icon-home" href="#">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to tweak this a bit, but it gives you the general idea.

Comment: how would I add the css class for the image?

Comment: I see now, after working out the padding should be good. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding some css to the image can force the text to align to the top of the image:

```
#menu img { vertical-align: top;}
```

or the middle:

```
#menu img {vertical-align: middle;}
```

The other option is to use a background image on the `a` tag combined with a little padding:

```
#menu a {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/1CRy2G5.png') no-repeat left center; 
    padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html below

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and add this in your css

```
#menu a.home {
    padding: 4px 20px 9px 30px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/1CRy2G5.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/nuSLH/13/)

Answer (score 0):

size of img tag gotten bigger because the requested img not found. My suggestion is, how about remove that img **if requested img not found**

you can use `onerror="this.remove()"`

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nuSLH/14/